# Tengo un renglon en sql con un caracter en forma de cuadro vacio y de tamaño pequeño

Tags: sql, servidor

tengo un pequeño pero gran problema en SQL server, tengo una tabla la cual tiene varios registros con caracteres no alfanumericos, tales como el simbolo del euro, #, @, !  ? y demas que pueden ser encontrados en una tabla ascii, https://www.asciitable.com, bueno, varios renglones contienen informacion que si la copias y la pegas en el editor de SQL Server, no muestra nada, pero si la copias y la pegas en el editor de notepad++ te muestra un texto con fondo negro que dice SOH y STX, entonces, en el resultado de la consulta de SQL, no me muestra mas que esos registros pero si quiero hacerles un delete no se como eliminarlos si no puedo copiar y pegar el contenido del renglon en el editor de SQL.

alguien me entiende o tiene alguna idea de como resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se me ocurre que puedes hacer es guardar en la base de datos el numero equivalente al codigo ascii en lugar de almacenar el propio código ascii y desde programacion ya desde c#, java, python o lo que use convierte dicho codigo en ascii.Por otro lado para eliminar los registros (`delete from tabla`) sin where deberia eliminarlos todos, si tiene datos importantes la tabla use [like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: Gracias, lo resolvi hace 40 minutos y vengo conectandome, lo que hice fue comparar mi tabla con otras tablas que tengan el mismo el mismo nombre del campo y si mi tabla 1 tiene un valor que no exista en las demas, pues les aplique un delete. y listo.

Comment: de esa manera elimine o limpie mi tabla con valores no alfanumericos